# Can't run npm start command (Node.js)

Tags: node.js

I have a npm start script like this:

```
"start": "NODE_ENV=development PORT=3003 nodemon app.js"
```

but when I run it I get the following output:

```
'NODE_ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I am using VSCode with Powershell, does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
SET NODE_ENV=development
PORT=3003
nodemon app.js
```

for windows. The one you tried works for Linux

Comment: Now I don't get an error, but nodemon doesn't run app.js for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This command works fine on linux, but windows does not recognize the **NODE_ENV** command.
to fix this install this package globally :

```
npm install -g win-node-env
```

see [win-node-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win-node-env)

Answer (score 0):

This command works fine in linux, for windows use:-

```
  "start": "set NODE_ENV=development&&PORT=3003&&nodemon app.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env#readme) as dev dependency which run scripts that set and use environment variables across platforms

```
npm i cross-env -D
```

Change to this :

`"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development PORT=3003 nodemon app.js"`

Best solution will be to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to save environment variables